# How do I query XHTML using python?

Tags: python, html

I have created a simple test harness in python for my ASP .net web site.

I would like to look up some HTML tags in the resulting page to find certain values.\

What would be the best way of doing this in python?

eg (returned page):

```
<div id="ErrorPanel">An error occurred......</div>
```

would display (in std out from python):

```
Error: .....
```

or

```
<td id="dob">23/3/1985</td>
```

would display:

```
Date of birth: 23/3/1985
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to parse XML, as you state in your question's title, or HTML, as you show in the text of the question?  For the latter, I recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) -- download it and install it, then, once having made a `soup` object out of the HTML, you can easily locate the tag with a certain id (or other attribute), e.g.:

```
errp = soup.find(attrs={'id': 'ErrorPanel'})
if errp is not None:
  print 'Error:', errp.string
```

and similarly for the other case (easily tweakable e.g. into a loop if you're looking for non-unique attributes, and so on).

Comment: I would like to parse HTML (XHTML).

Comment: Keep in mind, Beautiful Soup is designed to parse sloppy HTML, and it might not work on theoretically correct XHTML. On the other hand, a correct XML parser will choke on bad inputs that Beautiful Soup will parse.

Comment: @wisty, I've never had any problem using BeautifulSoup to parse XHTML -- can you think of any specific example?  (URL would be welcome, tx!)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with [lxml](http://lxml.de/). It [handles HTML](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) [very well](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/), and you can use [CSS selectors](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) for querying DOM, which makes it particularly attractive if you use libraries like jQuery regularly.